# Path variables and environmental variables

Tags: c, unix

I am trying to get the command through parent and execute it in different process(child process).

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(){
 pid_t pid = -1;
 int status = -1;
 char* ip = malloc(20);
 char* a[20];
 int pd[2];
 char* path = NULL;

 path = getenv("PATH");
 printf("\n path : %s \n",path);

 a[0] = malloc(10);

 while(1){
  pipe(pd);
  pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0){
   //printf("\n Child! - pid : %d \n",getpid());
   sleep(1);
   close(pd[1]);
   read(pd[0],ip,20);
   a[0] = ip;
   //execl(ip,ip,NULL);
   execv(path,a);
   exit(0);
  }
  else{
   //printf("\n Parent! - pid : %d \n",getpid());
   printf("(Enter a executable)$  ");
   scanf("%s",ip);
   //printf("\n %s \n",ip);
   close(pd[0]);
   write(pd[1],ip,20);
   waitpid(pid,&status,0);
   //printf("\n The child %d exited with status : %d \n",pid,status);
  }
 }
 free(ip);
 return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between the path and the environment. The getenv function gives me the whole path of the executable. The above program is not executing the command ls -l.

I want to execute the commands ls -l and the output should display on the screen as well as it should be stored in a file.
I tried to do execute the command ls -l. But its not executing. 
Is there a way to output the ls -l to a file when its outputing on the screen?

Comment: Return codes, return codes, return codes.  Save yourself time and sanity with `perror` and/or `strerror`.

Comment: The environment contains string pairs of variable names and their values.  PATH is one of those variables and contains the paths to various executables.  It can contain one or (likely) *many* such paths separated by a colon.  Your `execv` is going to flame out.  Look at what you print out for path.  Look at what you are passing as 'a' to `execv`.  Then match them up to what `execv` expects and notice what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

yes, there is a way to output to the screen and to a file at the same time, it is called `tee`.

```
    ls -l | tee your_output_file
```

Comment: Is this really what OP is asking for?

Comment: I think so. At least it solves the the last question in the OP.

Comment: Maybe.  Hard to say.  I couldn't figure if this what he wants to debug or he wants his program to write to both.

Answer (score 0):

You run `execv(path,a)`, using `path` as the first parameter, but you have set `path` to be the contents of the `PATH` environment variable. `PATH` is a list of directories for the shell to search for an executable; the first argument to `execv` should be the path of the executable to call. (Alternatively, `execlp` and some other variants can search the `PATH`` environment variable.)

There are some other problems with your code. It looks like the entire of what was typed in is used as the name of the program (e.g. it will look for an executable with the five-character name "ls -l"), and will break for commands longer than about 20 characters.